# Using static member of a class as an useEffect() dependency

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, static, singleton

I have the following situation.

**1)** A store class that's sort of a singleton pattern. I'm fetching asynchronously data from  a secure store and storing it `static myStoreValue: string` in order to avoid re-fetching the value from store if I already have it.

```
// MyStore.ts
export class StaticData {
  static myStoreValue: string | undefined
}
```

**2)** A component/screen that I want to re-render whenever that store value is being changed. The store value is changing using a visual switch available in some other screen.

```
//  MyScreen.ts
useEffect(()=>{
        fetchDataFromAPI();
    }, [StaticData.myStoreValue])
```

This approach doesn't seem to work, the useEffect() doesn't trigger when `StaticData.myStoreValue` changes.

***Why is it wrong and what would be the correct approach? Thank you.***

Comment: I'm not sure it will work since `StaticData.myStoreValue` is not state and is likely not defined in the component body. The class member doesn't cause the component to re-render

Comment: An effect only triggers when a dependency value has changed *when the component re-renders*. But changing your global store doesn't cause your component to re-render in the first place.